# What to do after your client rejected your designs?

Tags: logo

I'm not sure how else to write the title, but here goes!

I'm currently designing a new logo for an organization. I have designed various mockups sketches, but my client has rejected them all, and I have to go back to square one. I initially gave the client a design brief for her to fill out, but should I file another, revised one or should I just design more with the design brief I already have?

Sorry if this question might sound awkward; I'm not sure how else to phrase it.

Thank you! :-)

Comment: The point is: Whas the square one accepted? Sauqre two?

Answer (score 1):

I usually explain the client in the first meeting the process that starts with a different method according to the value of the project and complexity. After I agree a quote and the maximum of 2 revisions free I request extra value for new revisions. The branding process goes by phases and there is an agreement that the client needs to sign ( a contract) that is updated at every phase. This way you get some control and it is more simple for the client too, the project develops better. In your situation now if it is not working try to explain to your client that revisions need to be kept to a minimum due to time constraints and efficiency of the project. Be nice, give great customer care but keep the eye on doing a quality project that doesn't diver everywhere. Be assertive.